# What does it mean to pass a parameter of function type in C++?

Tags: c++, function, types, arguments

A while back I found that it's possible to write a C++ function that takes a parameter of function type (**not** function pointer type!). For example here's a function that takes a callback function that accepts and returns a double:

```
void MyFunction(double function(double));
```

My question is what it means to have a variable of function type, since you can't declare one in any other context.  Semantically, how is it different from a function pointer or reference to a function?  Is there an important difference between function pointers and variables of function type that I should be aware of?

Comment: I've never seen C++ like that before.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible in C++. Can you give a example wher this was possible?

Comment: This is one of those things like array shorthand `arrData == &arrData[0]` but I haven't seen it since `boost::function` showed up on the seen and when lambda functions are fully supported that'll change things too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just like `void f(int x[])` is the same as `void f(int* x)`, the following two are identical:

```
void MyFunction(double function(double)); 
void MyFunction(double (*function)(double));
```

Or, in official language (C++03 8.3.5/3), when determining the type of a function,

> After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type "array of `T`" or "function returning `T`" is adjusted to be "pointer to `T`" or "pointer to function returning `T`," respectively.

Comment: Awesome!  That perfectly answers my question.

Comment: There are rare occasions where the ISO Standard is clear and understandable.